# codecoverage isn't checking a project I want, and runsettings doesn't seem to fix it

Tags: visual-studio, runsettings

I have a solution. In that solution, I have 4 projects, and an additional project for tests. Coverage is checking 2 of those projects and the test project. I don't really care about excluding the tests, but I do need the 1 project that is for some reason being missed.

I created a .runsettings file and hooked it up in  visual studio.

```
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <ModulePaths>
              <Include>
                <!-- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159530.aspx
                  If <Include> is empty, then code coverage processing includes all assemblies (.dll and
                  .exe files) that are loaded and for which .pdb files can be found, except for items
                  that match a clause in an <Exclude> list.
                -->
              </Include>
            </ModulePaths>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

But that didn't find the project. So I tried a ModulePath for "anything" and also tried to explicitly add the DataLoader and DataAccess projects (the one not being checked for coverage)

```
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <ModulePaths>
              <Include>
                <ModulePath>.*</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>src/DataLoader/.*</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>src/DataAccess/.*</ModulePath>
              </Include>
            </ModulePaths>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

But it still doesn't work. I can find all kinds of results for how to *exclude* something from my runsettings, but how can I fix something incorrectly not being included?

My solution structure looks like this:

- Solution

  - Solution.sln
  - CodeCoverage.runsettings
  - ... etc...
  - src/

    - DataLoader/ (✖️ not checked for coverage)

      - DataLoader.xproj
      - ...
      - bin/Debug/net461/DataLoader.exe and .pdb
    - DataAccess/ (✖️)

      - DataAccess.xproj
      - ...
      - bin/Debug/net461/DataAccess.exe and .pdb
    - DataService/ (✔️)

      - DataService.xproj
      - ...
      - bin/Debug/net461/DataService.exe and .pdb
    - DataModels/ (✔️)

      - DataModels.xproj
      - ...
      - bin/Debug/net452/DataModels.dll and .pdb
  - test/Solution.Test/ (✔️)

    - bin/Debug/net461/Solution.Test.dll and .pdb
    - ...
    - Solution.Test.xproj